# insert in mysql issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is how the code looks for the insert.php file. Every time I run this code I get the same error that my variables are not defined. Below also you have my index page

```
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = 'root';
        $dbpass = 'admin';
        $dbname = 'test_emilian';
        $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        // check the connection
        if ($con->connect_errno){
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error);
        }
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']);
        $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first']);
        $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['last']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
        $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mobile']);
        $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['date']);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['gender']);
        $cnp = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['cnp']);
     //made the INSERT duction   


$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO useri (first,last,email,mobile,date,gender,cnp) values ('".$id."','".$first."','".$last."','".$email."','".$mobile."','".$date."','".$gender."','".$cnp."')";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$AddQuery))
        {echo 'Not Inserted';
        }else{
        echo 'Inserted Successfully';
        }
```

This is where I have defined the variables

```
        echo "<tr><form action=insert.php method = post>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =first></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =last></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =email></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =mobile></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =date></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =gender></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name =cnp></input></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=submit name =add value = add>" ."</td</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

at the end is not inserting anything.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Name attributes must be quoted `name="email"`

Comment: `input` tags are self-closing, no `</input>` needed.

Comment: thanks for our advice, made the changes but still nothing!

Comment: So I ve done all the modifications and still not connecting?PLEASE heeelp!!

Comment: Run print_r($_POST); in insert.php and see what the output is.

Comment: Have you taken the form out of the table? Did you read and follow the links I closed your question with?

Comment: I don't see any field named id ..
try removing `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']);`

Comment: @KevinP //when I run that it gave me this: Array ( [first] => sa [last] => [email] => [mobile] => [date] => [gender] => [cnp] => [add] => add ) Not Insertedï»¿

Comment: Let's see what the error is

Add this to the first condition if it fails

`echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: I have removed the field: $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id']); and still the same

Comment: it gives me this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') values ('sas','','','','','','')' at line 1

Comment: Remove '".$id."', from VALUES, your column count doesn't match your value count.

Comment: removed id from values, run again the echo mysqli_error($con); and now it says: Incorrect date value: '4' for column 'date' at row 1. How to bypass that?

Comment: You can't insert 4 into a date column, either skip inserting data into that column or make sure it's a valid date in Y-m-d format.

Comment: Sorry for that is my mistake, tried to run again the  and still says undefined index :(

Comment: it appears an error for all indexes such as: first,last,email, mobile...

Comment: do you have a skype acc?we can chat there